# No subnets found for the default

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

Here is the error when rendering the stack:

```
No subnets found for the default VPC 'vpc-23fc4145'. Please specify a subnet.
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying a subnet?

Comment: Yes. But it is not using the associated resources in CF.

Comment: Edit your question and include the template.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you have default VPC in the region you have selected. Apparently, this error means you have deleted your default VPC in the region you have selected.

Please create a default VPC for the region you want - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/create-a-new-default-vpc-using-aws-console-or-cli/

If you are facing a problem with default VPC creation then please raise a ticket to AWS.

Comment: As of July 2017, you can now create a default VPC using the CLI or Console. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/create-a-new-default-vpc-using-aws-console-or-cli/

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for it. I didn't see this update yet. Thank you very much so letting me know. I will update answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I needed to specify the subnet in the EC2's NetworkInterfaces.

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Deploy a simple Amazon Linux Instance and allow SSH connectivity.

Resources:
  TheInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-8c1be5f6
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - GroupSet:
            - Ref: TheSecurityGroup
          AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
          DeviceIndex: "0"
          DeleteOnTermination: "true"
          SubnetId: # <---------------------
            Ref: TheSubnet # <---------------------
  TheSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      VpcId:
        Ref: TheVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "22"
          ToPort: "22"
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  TheVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
  TheSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: TheVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: "us-east-1a"
```